# Search string from csv column and print value_counts for string vallue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Ok, Im having trouble searching my csv file columns for specific text in that column and doing a value_count based on certain text found. I'm new to python and everything I search is different than how I even get my values printed.

For instance, I see slot of data frames being searched by `df(df['column'])` however, mine is different in that I call my data by `df.colC.value_counts`. I'm not understanding the difference but, glad it works at least for this portion.

Below is my code I'm needing help with.

```py
import pandas as pd
import ssl

#print(pd)
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

#Reading data from Integrator API and stripping un needed columns
df = pd.read_csv("https://someurlhere", sep=',', usecols=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE'])

#Creating new file with API data grabbed
df.to_csv('localfilelocation.csv')


#Reading file for to get values
df = pd.read_csv('localfilelocation.csv', sep=',', usecols=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE'])

#prints counts for each source in datraframe
#print(df)

#works and prints counts based on colC data
print(df.colC.value_counts())

#Tried multiple scenarios to search that doesn't work
#print(df.colC.value_counts.(str.contains['acct']))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is broken. Try this:

```
df[df.colC.str.contains('acct')].colC.value_counts()
```

Where in the square brackets part you filter out everything that does not have 'acct' as part of the string, and then you invoke value counts on the filtered part. At least that's what it seems you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Just what i was looking for.